# How to covert an ObjectId to its integer value?

Tags: mongoose

I tried the following:

```
id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(123); 
ID = parseInt(id.valueOf(), 16);
```

ID is not 123 but is 2.2774854096055252e+21.

How do I get back the original number used to create the ObjectId object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [valueOf](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.valueOf/) and from there take the part you need. In your case that is generationTime since [mongoId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#ObjectId) is composed of few parts:

> - 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
> - 3-byte machine identifier,
> - 2-byte process id, and
> - 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

```
var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(123); 
console.log(id.valueOf().generationTime) // gives you 123
```